# how to get datetimepicker value with Date and current time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

i have used the GMDatepicker. i need to take the datetime value along with date.

my code:

DateTime dateval= ((GMDatePicker)GrdDynamicControls.FooterRow.FindControl("frmDateTime")).Date;

this gives me the date 6/26/2010 12.00pm. and not the current time.

how to get the date with current time over here.....???

Comment: Do you want the *current* time associated with whatever date the user selects or merely if they select the current date? Meaning, if it is 5 in the afternoon when the user selects November 5, 1955, you want to record that time as 1955-Nov-5 5:00 PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *current* time, just:

```
dateval += DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

It's slightly odd to pick a different date but keep the current time though...